# Spring boot and Nagios for remote server monitoring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nagios, nrpe

I have some questions and I will be very grateful if I receive your answer.

Concerning a project that I have to do in school .I have to develop a web application to supervise  some remote machines ( CentOS VM ), the technologies that I have to work with is JAVA and Nagios-Core [ JAVA-EE architecture and specially the framework Spring ( Spring boot2.0.0 ) with JPA and MySQL database ] .
Before starting to code I want to understand the architecture that I have to implement in my web application and how it will communicate with Nagios and the JNRPE in the remote server .

In my application there is two roles : Admin and User

- The admin is the one who add the remote machines and its configuration ( into a html Form ) , I have to put the configurations into a file which is the config file of Nagios.
- The User is the one who supervise the remote server , when he choose the server , the check NRPE do his job by calling the JNRPE and wait for the response .
  The response will be presented in the Nagios view.

**From what i have to start ? can you give a global vision about this project ,and what are steps to follow ?**

Comment: help with what? You've outlined your project and stated that you're looking to understand the architecture but I don't see a question that can be answered.

Comment: @RobertH , i  just edited my question. I want to know if is it possible what I want to do or not ? and if yes how can i do it

Comment: I think you may be confused as to what the StackOverflow community does: We help answer specific questions related to programming - We're definitely able to assist with the technologies you've mentioned. What we're not though is a resource to help you define a vision for a project, nor are we a tutorial site. For what its worth though, here is my advice: Research the technolgies you are using via the official websites documentation. Understand Nagios and how it works, install it. Use it. Presuming you know how to program write some basic programs to interact with Nagios and build from there.

Comment: As you do the requisite research you will have questions about what you're reading and learning. Research those questions and if you're unable to find your answer then ask those specific questions and I'm confident that someone will be glad to help

Comment: I think you're thinking of me as an expert, I'm still a student.
I documented on Nagios, I even installed it, and I tested it.
But to realize this application I must first ask an expert in java because I did not find anything in this subject (java and najios) . 
I work with spring boot and java ( for 2 small years ) but Nagios and monitoring a remote server , it's new to me . I have also a bad english  . Thanks for your help @RobertH

Comment: Nope, I'm thinking of you as a student :) I'm just suggesting that you're asking your questions here too early in your process as you're unable to ask a question that is on topic for StackOverflow (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ). Good luck with your project!